# Odoo How to Know Which View File Based on Url

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I'm new to Odoo 9 and want to learn the basic. Given i click on top menu `Purchases` and then on menu item i click `Purchase Order`. The url for this menu is `http://localhost:8069/web?debug=#page=0&limit=80&view_type=list&model=purchase.order&menu_id=223&action=289`. With this url how do i know which xml and python file i can modify if i want to do some modification? and also how do i know the name of the view to be inherited?

I know rails and in rails it can be found on the routes file (`routes.rb`). I'm not expecting the exact same way but there should be a way to do this since all i know Odoo development is about modifying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this URL you can't find the view, but if you are in debug mode and click on BUG icon you will see `view_id`. See picture below.

[image]

You will get all info in modal window.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!. I'm begin to understand Odoo